# XCTest exception when using keyValueObservingExpectationForObject:keyPath:handler:

Tags: ios, macos, key-value-observing, xctest

In my unit tests, I am using the `-[XCTestCase keyValueObservingExpectationForObject:keyPath:handler:]` method in order to ensure that my NSOperation finishes, here is the [code from my XCDYouTubeKit project](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit/blob/aff06745b33095f9d3780bf307eb7984c37b8a37/XCDYouTubeKit%20Tests/XCDYouTubeVideoOperationTestCase.m#L38-L53):

```c
- (void) testStartingOnBackgroundThread
{
    XCDYouTubeVideoOperation *operation = [[XCDYouTubeVideoOperation alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:nil languageIdentifier:nil];
    [self keyValueObservingExpectationForObject:operation keyPath:@"isFinished" handler:^BOOL(id observedObject, NSDictionary *change)
    {
        XCTAssertNil([observedObject video]);
        XCTAssertNotNil([observedObject error]);
        return YES;
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        XCTAssertFalse([NSThread isMainThread]);
        [operation start];
    });
    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5 handler:nil];
}
```

This test always passes when I run it locally on my Mac but sometimes it [fails on Travis](https://travis-ci.org/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit/builds/67480007#L410) with this error:

> failed: caught "NSRangeException", "Cannot remove an observer <_XCKVOExpectation 0x1001846c0> for the key path "isFinished" from <XCDYouTubeVideoOperation 0x1001b9510> because it is not registered as an observer."

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Cœur [The general consensus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274906/should-questions-that-violate-api-terms-of-service-be-flagged) is that it is not the responsibility of stackoverflow users or moderators to enforce the ToS of other web sites.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is correct, you have found a bug in the XCTest framework. Here is an in depth explanation, you can skip to the end of this answer if you are just looking for a workaround.

When you call `keyValueObservingExpectationForObject:keyPath:handler:`, an `_XCKVOExpectation` object is created under the hood. It is responsible for observing the object/keyPath you passed. Once the KVO notification has fired, the `_safelyUnregister` method is called, this is where the observer is removed. Here is the (reverse engineered) implementation of the `_safelyUnregister` method.

```c
@implementation _XCKVOExpectation

- (void) _safelyUnregister
{
    if (!self.hasUnregistered)
    {
        [self.observedObject removeObserver:self forKeyPath:self.keyPath];
        self.hasUnregistered = YES;
    }
}

@end
```

This method is called once again at the end of `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:handler:` and when the `_XCKVOExpectation` object is deallocated. Note that the operation terminates on a background thread but the test is run on the main thread. So you have a race condition: if `_safelyUnregister` is called on the main thread before the `hasUnregistered` property is set to `YES` on the background thread, the observer is removed twice, causing the *Cannot remove an observer* exception.

So in order to workaround this issue, you have to protect the `_safelyUnregister` method with a lock. Here is a code snippet for you to compile in your test target that will take care of fixing this bug.

```c
#import <objc/runtime.h>

__attribute__((constructor)) void WorkaroundXCKVOExpectationUnregistrationRaceCondition(void);
__attribute__((constructor)) void WorkaroundXCKVOExpectationUnregistrationRaceCondition(void)
{
    SEL _safelyUnregisterSEL = sel_getUid("_safelyUnregister");
    Method safelyUnregister = class_getInstanceMethod(objc_lookUpClass("_XCKVOExpectation"), _safelyUnregisterSEL);
    void (*_safelyUnregisterIMP)(id, SEL) = (__typeof__(_safelyUnregisterIMP))method_getImplementation(safelyUnregister);
    method_setImplementation(safelyUnregister, imp_implementationWithBlock(^(id self) {
        @synchronized(self)
        {
            _safelyUnregisterIMP(self, _safelyUnregisterSEL);
        }
    }));
}
```

**EDIT**

This bug has been [fixed in Xcode 7 beta 4](https://twitter.com/0xced/status/624149536156569600).